# Catch mouse click event

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I have really googled this to death but not finding anything that helps much.
I am using C# WPF cefsharp.wpf cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser

All I want to do is when ever the user clicks anything on the web-page I want to catch the mouse click event in c#. Reason is that I have javascript running on the page that registers what was clicked and passes back a value. So I need to get that value from the javascript. Everything is setup. I just cant get C# to register that the browser was clicked. C# doesnt need to know what element was clicked on the page, the javascript handles that for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using wpf or winforms ?

Comment: Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.addhandler?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_UIElement_AddHandler_System_Windows_RoutedEvent_System_Delegate_System_Boolean_ to register your handler and set handledEventsToo to true

Comment: Hi no using WPF

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a handler on mouse up event

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myBrowser" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>

myBrowser.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Browser_MouseUp), true);

private static void Browser_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{//Check for button that was clicked and e.Source ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are capturing a click event in your JavaScript to get what is selected on the page that, in effect, is your event. In your JavaScript invoke a C# method from that click.

For example in an app I wrote I had a D3 page rendered in CefSharp that showed a force layout diagram, when the user clicked on an item in the force layout the JavaScript sent the id of that item to the C# which in turn returned a serialised piece of data back to JavaScript which was then displayed (effectively I had a C# class that acted as a layer between CefSharp and my model handling serialisation to and from the JavaScript). It sounds like you need to take an approach like this for what you are trying to achieve rather than needing an actual click event on the browser control itself.

I've added some example code below that shows a button on screen in CefSharp (as defined in index.html). When the button is clicked it passes a value from the page to the JsHandler class which in turn shows a message box with the value.

**Mainwindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="CefSharpWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CefSharpWPF"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Row="0"
                                x:Name="Browser" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Mainwindow.cs**

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        JsHandler jsHandler = new JsHandler();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Browser.Address = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/index.html";
            Browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("jsHandler", jsHandler);
        }
    }
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                CefSharp.BindObjectAsync("jsHandler", "jsHandler");
            </script>
            <title>Test Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button onclick="window.jsHandler.handleJsCall(1)">button</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**JsHandler.cs**

```
    class JsHandler
    {
        public void HandleJsCall(int arg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Value Provided From JavaScript: {arg.ToString()}", "C# Method Called");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That is definitely something I haven't considered. What you are describing is actually exactly what I am trying to do. Return an id from the javascript to get some data out of my database for the software to handle. so you are suggesting something like.

Javascript:

if (Javascriptcondition > 0) {
<%CsharpFunction();%>
}
C#:

protected void CsharpFunction()
{
 // Notification.show();
}

Comment: I've added some example code to my answer which achieves what i think you want in a simplistic form. In real usage you can pass objects to and from the javascript as JSON to allow you to pass complex objects easily but CefSharp does handle conversion of many standard types.

Comment: @DaeDaLuS_015 - Excellent Answer to something that's hard to find a good explanation of. Thanks :)